# Confirm successful print programmatically in windows

Tags: c#, printing

My company is developing a financial application.
Now we have to deal with a new law that demands that we take different actions whether a receipt is printed or not.

The receipts are printed on a laserprinter on A4 paper using the standard print queue in windows. Is there any way to programmatically check if a certain print job actually has succeeded? The module requiring this is developed in c#.

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of a fully managed way to perform this. Interop with [FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162722(VS.85).aspx) and [FindNextPrinterChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162723(VS.85).aspx) might be required. You could also take a look at [existing wrappers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/printwatchvbnet.aspx) allowing to monitor the printer queue.